# HTML code not working correctly in Joomla1.5

Tags: joomla1.5

Hi just started Joomla1.5

Included some HTML code a table and lists within my Joomla1.5 but table border not showing
and lists not aligned at all not sure why.

Imported the extension that allows one to embedd HTML code and used the 
{loadposition CustomHTMLpostion} within a content article tested the HTML code with
Textpad works fine but not in Joomla1.5 - any ideas?

Comment: how do i do this as when I added it it just displayed the result even though I was typing in the code

Answer (score 0):

Check CSS files of your template, they must have been styling your HTML.
Use firebug(for firefox), to check which CSS styling is being applied on your table or list.
Then override that CSS.